# Entity not managed error occurs when trying to create a custom JPARepository in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am relatively new to Spring Boot and am looking to learn it by building a simple project. I am trying to setup a simple Rest API using Spring Boot. I used the spring initializer website to generate my project and made sure to download all the necessary dependencies. here is my **build.gradle** file

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.app'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am facing an issue when trying to run the application, I did try searching for my issue online, but none of the proposed solutions worked for me. The setup of my project is as follows, I have a **User entity** which is defined below

**User.java**

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "users_seq", sequenceName = "users_seq", initialValue = 1024)
public class User {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_seq")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String phoneNumber;

    // Getter and Setters
}
```

I also have a custom **UserRepository** interface which extends **JPARepository** as seen below

**UserRepository.java**

```
import com.app.code.entities.user.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("from User u where u.key = :key")
    public User getUserByKey(@Param("key") Long key);

    @Query("from User u where u.username = :username")
    public List<User> getExistingUserByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

All these files are present under **"com.app.code"** package, and I have added appropriate annotations in the main Springboot application class whcich point to my components, entities and repositories as seen below

**ServerApplication.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.app.code.*")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app.code.*"})
@EntityScan("com.app.code.*")
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The issue I face is when trying to run the application, I get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.app.code.repositories.user.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on ServerApplication: Not a managed type: class com.app.code.entities.user.User
```

This error only occurs when the application attempts to create a bean for **UserRepository**. When I remove the **UserRepository** from the **@EnableJpaRepositories** annotation, there is no error, and the User Entity is successfully being used in Controllers and Services. I did some digging online and I understand that the issue is something to do with spring boot using **jakarta** instead of **javax** from version 3.0.0 onwards. I am currently using **version 3.0.6 of Spring Boot** and am running **java version 19.0.2**. Is the issue due to a dependency mismatch that I am not aware of? I even tried generating a fresh project from spring initializer with the spring boot version of 2.7.13 and created a similar setup as above, and took care to use javax instead of jakarta, however I was faced with the same issue.

I apologize if the question is unclear, English is not my first language. If any additional details are needed, please let me know and I will provide them as best I can.

Comment: the packages in the `ServerApplication` annotations should not end in `.*`. They are already prefixes. You are basically telling Spring to search in packages starting with `com.app.code.*`. As long as your `ServerApplication` class is already in package `com.app.code` you do not even need the additional annotations, because Spring searches the package (and its subpackages) of the main class by default

Comment: @FlorianCramer thank you for your advice, I have removed the `.*` from the paths. The reason for me using the annotations is because I have kept the `ServerApplication` class in a separate `com.app.server` package and not `com.app.code` package.

Comment: There is an error in repository method getUserByKey. It uses field named 'key' which is not present in the entity User. BTW: For loading by ID you can just use the predefined method findById. Without explicitly define it in the repository. The same is valid for findByUsername.